# Hammer.js 2 only intermittently recognizes pinch gesture on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, pinchzoom, hammer.js

I recently updated to the latest version of hammer js and I've noticed that my pinch zoom is now very poorly recognized on iOS, though it seems fine on Android.

Here's the code I use to create the pinch sensitive objects:

```
var hammerifiedElements = $(elements).hammer({ touchAction: auto });

hammerifiedElements.each(function () {
   var mc = $(this).data("hammer");
   var pinchRecogniser = mc.get('pinch');
   pinchRecogniser.set({ enable: true, threshold: 0 });
})
```

I've logged the hammer events and I've found that on the occasions it is not recognizing a pinch, it is recognizing a single-touch pan.

```
console.log(event.type+" "+event.pointers.length)
```

On the rare occasion it works I see

```
pinch 2
```

but about 80% of the time it came out

```
pan 1
```

even though I was using two fingers.

This is on a div which has some scrollable content. Changing the touchAction property so that the native scroll no longer works (I don't want this. I was just testing.) doesn't seem to help.

I also have the relevant meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
```